# Batch files created by python not running, but edit by notepad works

Tags: python, python-3.x, editor, slurm

I intend to use python and create a bunch of batch files, but the batch files created by python cannot be uploaded, while the same codes manually inputted can. I was wondering why.

My code is as follows

```
import os

os.chdir("c:/Users/alku/Documents/Work/ToDo/data")
## creating a folder to place submit codes
if not os.path.exists('submit'):
    os.makedirs('submit')

depvar = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
          "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
          "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"]
##creating corresponding batch codes for supercomputer
###creating a master file
fmaster= open('submit/submit-R-00.csh',"wb+")
fmaster.write(bytes(
'#!/bin/csh' + "\n" +
'#SBATCH --time=00:10:00' + "\n" +
'#SBATCH --mem=6000' + "\n" +
'#SBATCH --cores=1' + "\n"
, encoding='utf8'))
fmaster.close()

for i in depvar:
    fmaster= open('submit/submit-R-00.csh',"ab+")
    f= open('submit/submit-R-' + str(i) + '.csh',"wb+")
    f.write(bytes(
    '#!/bin/csh' + "\n" +
    '#SBATCH --time=96:00:00' + "\n" +
    '#SBATCH --mem=256000' + "\n" +
    '#SBATCH --cores=8' + "\n" +
    'module load R/3.5.1' + "\n" +
    'Rscript alku-COVIDImpact031-quantregForest-part'+ str(i) + '.R'
    , encoding='utf8'))
    ##writing into the master file
    fmaster.write(bytes(
    'sbatch submit-R-' + str(i) + '.csh'  + "\n"
    , encoding='utf8'))
```

and the results are something like

```
#!/bin/csh
#SBATCH --time=96:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=256000
#SBATCH --cores=8
module load R/3.5.1
Rscript alku-COVIDImpact031-quantregForest-part01.R
```

With a master file submit-R-00.csh to submit them

```
#!/bin/csh
#SBATCH --time=00:10:00
#SBATCH --mem=6000
#SBATCH --cores=1
sbatch submit-R-01.csh
sbatch submit-R-02.csh
sbatch submit-R-03.csh
sbatch submit-R-04.csh
sbatch submit-R-05.csh
sbatch submit-R-06.csh
sbatch submit-R-07.csh
sbatch submit-R-08.csh
sbatch submit-R-09.csh
sbatch submit-R-10.csh
sbatch submit-R-11.csh
sbatch submit-R-12.csh
sbatch submit-R-13.csh
sbatch submit-R-14.csh
sbatch submit-R-15.csh
sbatch submit-R-16.csh
sbatch submit-R-17.csh
sbatch submit-R-18.csh
sbatch submit-R-19.csh
sbatch submit-R-20.csh
sbatch submit-R-21.csh
sbatch submit-R-22.csh
sbatch submit-R-23.csh
sbatch submit-R-24.csh
```

However, when I upload these files to our university supercomputer, the supercomputer almost cancel the jobs immediately. Furthermore, the system creates an all empty output, so I cannot figure out what happens.

I then typed the exact same codes with notepads, and upload them to the supercomputer. Somehow this time it works. These two versions are exactly the same, and I also use vim to check the line breaker. Although the problem is solved, I am very curious why the same codes created by python cannot be submitted, while typed manually can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in For loop, after the write is done, you have to close the files

```
fmaster.close()
f.close()
```

try closing the file and retry
the best way to avoid missing `f.close()` is to use `with`, like:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    for line in f:
        # ... do stuff ...
```

this will automatically close the file. we dont need to explicity do `f.close()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! It works! What happens when I didn't close() my file? The codes look the same. Sorry for my stupid question, I am new to coding...

Answer (score 1):

use `with` to do operations on file. Eg.

```
with open("filename") as f:
    for line in f:
        # ... do stuff ...
```

to avoid explicitly closing the file